# intellij hotswap doesn't work: adding one local variable

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, hotswap

I am using OracleJVM with Intellij remote debugging. I am not doing any DCEVM fancy stuff. My code:

```
    public static String test() {
    String data; //new code
    if (some condition){
        //...
        data = "abc"; //new code
        //...
    }
}
```

After making the change, recompile the class and verifying 'hotswap' finished successfully, the static method is re-ran but debugger variables window says

> Cannot find local variable 'data'

Comment: Even without hotswap `data` variable is only available after the assignment.

Comment: i didn’t clarify. the breakpoint is after the assignment